# moving Esxi 5.5 VMs to Esxi 6.7

Tags: vmware, virtualization, vsphere, esxi

I have a production server that hosts 3 VM's over Esxi 5.5.
Back in the day, I used a customized HP image to get ESXi installed on the Proliant server.

I have purchased a new server with Esxi 6.7 installed and wonder if I can move my 3 VM's hosted on the old HP server onto my new server (running ESXi 6.7).

The HP server sits 1500Km away so is challenging to test.

Did anyone come across any challenges removing VM's from one Host to another running different ESXi versions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any problems in the transportation process, but need to decide which transportation method use.

You can install vCenter Server Appliance then migrate with Storage vMotion.

If you do not want to install vCenter, you can turn the VMs power off and get an OVF copy to export (more on OVF [here on vmware.com's site](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-AE61948B-C2EE-436E-BAFB-3C7209088552.html)). You can then add this again from the deploy OVF section.

Link below for Vcenter installation.

https://www.tayfundeger.com/vcenter-server-appliance-6-7-kurulumu-bolum-1.html
https://www.tayfundeger.com/vcenter-server-appliance-6-7-kurulumu-bolum-2.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VM objects are fairly backwards compatible and most go back quite a few years and a handful of versions, so you should be fine between those particular versions.

The biggest consideration is normally how to get the VM object data from point A to point B. Example:

- Are you using storage based replication?
- Are you SCPing the data directly from the hosts?
- Are you exporting the VMs, transporting the data, and importing them?
- Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The things you must take into account are:

1 - Hardware version. It's not possible to downgrade HW version through the ESXi UI. This won't be a problem in your case, as you are moving the VMs to a higher ESXi version that still supports ESXi 5.5's HW version. Once you have the VMs in the target server you can decide to upgrade to the most recent HW version for your new platform.

2 - VMFS version. ESXi 6.7 allows the use of VMFS-5 or VMFS-6, which is a newer version of the VMWare file system. You can indeed move VMs from VMFS-5 to VMFS-6. Nonetheless, unless it's unavoidable to do so, I would use the same VMFS version, as performing a cross-file system migration can make you fall into some incompatibilities that you should avoid.

3 - You will have to move your VMs over IP. If you don't own a VMWare license that allows you to migrate them, you can use an **[ESXi backup tool from 33hops.com](https://33hops.com/xsibackup-vmware-esxi-backup.html)** that is compatible with unlicensed Free ESXi.

This XSIBackup-DC is a well-tested tool that allows to live migrate VMs over IP in licensed or unlicense versions of ESXi.